# Using SQL Statement in TO_DATE Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I have to use SQL statement in TO_DATE function. Like:

```
TO_DATE((select MAX(VERSION) from TABLE_B),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

When I use TO_DATE like that, I encounter an error. Like:

> [Error] Execution (9: 32): ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Is there a way for using TO_DATE function like that?

Comment: The syntax you have is valid although, as the answers below say, it's an unusual way to go about it. The error message is not due to the syntax.

Comment: What is the data type of column `version` in table `table_b`? Best to confirm it, by running the command `describe table_b`. Then: what is a typical value in that column? I bet the data type is `varchar2` or similar, and typical values are like `12-APR-2017`. Then the format model provided to `to_date` should follow this; it should be 'DD-MON-YYYY`. Another possibility is that `version` is actually of `date` data type, in which case calling it within `to_date()` is wrong. You may be victim to internal conversions from date to string and then back to date, with incompatible format models.

Comment: In any case what you are doing in the query is logically incorrect, even if the syntax was right and even if you had not run into data problems. Presumably you want the most recent `version` - but if `version` is in string data type, then `31-DEC-2015` is later than `21-AUG-2017`, because the sorting is purely alphabetic, and the first character, 3, is after 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_date(max(version), 'mm/dd/yyyy') from table_b
```

might be a better choice. Note, though, that if VERSION column (it is ... what?  A string?) contains something that doesn't match that date format, TO_DATE will fail, exactly with an error you got. Therefore, make sure that data is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. VERSION column is a date. I want to use this SQL statement as a parameter in DataStage. In some cases, I'll send this SQL statement as a parameter and this parameter's type is a string. Because of that, I have to use the SQL statement in to_date function.

Comment: I'm afraid that you got it wrong. If VERSION's data type is DATE, you should **NOT** use TO_DATE against it, but **TO_CHAR** with appropriate format mask. The most common mistake people make is TO_DATE(SYSDATE), which is similar to your situation (as SYSDATE is a function which returns DATE data type). If you think I'm wrong, please, modify your message and provide test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample records) so that we could see what you have and, possibly, what to do with it in order to help you do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Apply it to the result of the query.

If `version` is a `DATE` column do **NOT** apply `to_date()` to it:

```
select MAX(VERSION)
from table_b;
```

If you want a specific output format from a `DATE` column, use `to_char()` instead:

```
select to_char(MAX(VERSION),'MM/DD/YYYY')
from table_b;
```